# How to say "The woman heard that I passed the test"?

Tags: grammar

So far, the word そうです is used to express "hearsay" sentences with I who is implicitly defined as the listener.

- 彼女は結婚したそうです。I heard that the woman got married.
- あなたは合格したそうです。I heard that you passed.

## My questions:

How is the sentence below in Japanese? If I want to say, for example.

> The woman heard that I passed the test.

Comment: Where is "heresay" in "The woman heard that I passed the test."? I think it would be translated as 「彼女は私が試験に合格したことを聞いた。」

Comment: "I passed the test" is a hearsay that the woman heard. It doesn't have to be true. Would the following convey this difference in meaning 「彼女は私が試験に合格したということを聞いた」?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did pass the test:
~ことを聞いた　
~と聞いた

If you did not pass the test, or there was not even a test:
~ことを聞いた*
~と聞いた

The usage of こと reflects the presupposition of truth on passing the test from the speaker's point of view.

*denotes unacceptability

Comment: I think it's very insightful of you to distinguish whether it really happened or not, but the "false" case has to be ～と聞いた, then it'll deserve +1.

Comment: @broccoliforest can ～と聞いた take on " ~ true" ? or is "false" definite?

Comment: <100% confidence. If you think you definitely passed, then you can't use it.

Comment: @broccoliforest how about という? the lifting of truth presupposition is not *necessarily true* right?

Comment: という only connects to nominals, and if you attach こと, it'll become true.

Comment: @broccoliforest I would like to continue this discussion in chat to improve this answer